# Codeigniter 4 issue with session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-4

I have this function in my codeigniter 4 controller

```
private function setUserSession($user)
{
    $data = [
        'id' => $user['id'],
        'username' => $user['username'],
        'phone' => $user['phone'],
        'firstname' => $user['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $user['lastname'],
        'bankname' => $user['bankname'],
        'acc_name' => $user['acc_name'],
        'account_number' => $user['account_number'],
        'whatsapp_group' => $user['whatsapp_group'],
        'whatsapp_phone' => $user['whatsapp_phone'],
        'email' => $user['email'],
        'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'reg_balance' => $user['reg_balance'],
        'reg_country' => $user['reg_country'],
        'status' => $user['status'],
        'mode' => $user['mode'],
        'isLoggedIn' => true,
    ];

    session()->set($data);
    return true;
}
```

I use

```
$username = session()->get('username');
$id = session()->get('id');
```

Globally to retrieve users details, but at times when a user logins in, he/she will be seeing another person's info until he refreshes two or more times before it bring out his own details.

Comment: Did you destroy the session properly on logout?

Comment: [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: yes, i did using  public function logout()
 {
  session()->destroy();
  return redirect()->to('login');
 }

Comment: How do you know that *he/she will be seeing another person's info*. Are you testing with a different device/browser per user or just with one browser and several tabs?

Comment: yes...i have a user account. I do experience it

Comment: A private method means it's not being called directly by the request so I have to ask, are you sure you're calling this private method everywhere that you should be?

Comment: I find it odd that this is a private method. Can we see the entire controller that sets the session data and the one that destroys the session data on logout?